# ReactJs map structure can't select by material-ui Selectable List component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm in trouble.
But I can't write text by English well...
※It may be difficult to read, but please forgive me.

---

I want to select ListItem component, but ListItem map structure can't select.

What I'm expecting is this.

[Selectable list](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list)

※At the bottom of the page

My output's rendering result is this.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a60eU.png)

ReactJS code is this.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import emails from './mails'
import {List, ListItem, makeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader';
import ActionGrade from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/grade';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin'; 
injectTapEventPlugin();
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List);

function wrapState(ComposedComponent) {
  return class SelectableList extends React.Component<{defaultValue: number}, {selectedIndex: number}>  {
    static propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.any.isRequired, 
    };
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handleRequestChange = this.handleRequestChange.bind(this);
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      });
    }

    handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      });
    };

    render() {
      let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          value={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
        >
          {children}
        </ComposedComponent>
      );
    }
  };
}

SelectableList = wrapState(SelectableList);


class App extends React.Component<any, any>{
  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: true,
        };

        this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    };

  handleNestedListToggle = (item) => {
        this.setState({
            open: item.state.open,
        });
   };

  handleToggle = (e) => {
        console.log("event", e);
        this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open,
        });
  };


  render () {
    const mapStructure = (nodes) => {
    if (nodes) {
      return nodes.map((node, index) => (      
        <ListItem
          value={node.id}
          key={index}
          primaryText={node.primaryText}
          leftIcon={<ActionGrade />}
          initiallyOpen={this.state.open}
          primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
          onNestedListToggle={this.handleNestedListToggle}
          onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
          nestedItems={mapStructure(node.menu)}
        />
      ));
    }
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <br />
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div>
                <Subheader>list</Subheader>
                  <SelectableList>
                    {mapStructure(emails)}
                  </SelectableList> 
          </div>        
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>  
    )
  }  
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

./mails is this.

```
export default [
      {
        id: 1,
        primaryText: "test1"
        ,
        menu: [
          {
            id: 2,
            primaryText: "test2"
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            primaryText: "test3"
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            primaryText: "test4"
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            primaryText: "test5" 
            ,
            menu: [
              {
                id: 6,
                primaryText: "test6" 
              },
              {
                id: 7,
                primaryText: "test7" 
              }]
          }],
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        primaryText: "test8"
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        primaryText: "test9"
      }
    ];
```

Additional information will be added if necessary.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with list toggles properties:
 primaryTogglesNestedList, onNestedListToggle. Maybe they somehow override the usual behavior of SelectableList click event. Try to remove them and see whether it works for you:

```
<ListItem
  value={node.id}
  key={index}
  primaryText={node.primaryText}
  leftIcon={<ActionGrade />}
  initiallyOpen={this.state.open}
  onTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
  nestedItems={mapStructure(node.menu)}
/>
```

Comment: Very very thanks!!     

Sorry. in addition, once more.    

Surely, I removed them, so output move properly.    

If possible, I want to open/close toggle by click target rectangle box.    

For example, If I will click "test5" rectangle box, so "test6" and "test7" will close ,too.    
(I don't want user to click right open/close button, because it looks like little hard to understand.)   
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a60eU.png)  

If possible, please teach me how to implement.